# cron job not working automatically

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to do [this](http://raspberrywebserver.com/cgiscripting/rpi-temperature-logger/building-an-sqlite-temperature-logger.html).
It doesn't work as it should, if I run the monitor.py manually the script works
But the cron job doesn't run automatically I think, even dough I configured it to run every minute I don't see new data on the database.
How can I debug this please?

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: try logging say hello world or data as a first line in your python script from your script and see if its logging in?

Comment: Try looking for errors in your cron log, usually in `/var/log/cron`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I found the problem:
the command that starts with /1 * * * * etc has to start
*/1 * * * * etc